# A probability density function with square integrable second derivative on $\mathbb R$.

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Suppose $p(x),x\in \mathbb R$ is a density function, and $p''(x)$ satisfies $\int (p''(x))^2\mathrm d x < \infty$. I want know how to prove $p(x)$ is bounded on $\mathbb R$. Thanks！

Remark: this problem comes from the proof of Proposition 1.6 of "Introduction to Nonparametric Estimation" by B.Tsybakov.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cheap trick: Use the Fourier transform.

Say $f=\hat p$. Then $p''\in  L^2$ implies $x^2f(x)\in L^2$, so Cauchy-Schwarz implies $\int_{|x|>1}|f(x)|<\infty$. But $f$ is continuous, so actually $f\in L^1(\Bbb R)$. So $p\in C_0(\Bbb R)$.

Comment: Thanks, David! But I'm not familiar with Fourier transform, could you say more about why $p''\in L^2$ implies $x^2f(x) \in L^2$?

Comment: Oh, I just notice thatsince $f = \hat p$, the Fourier transform of $p''$ is $(2\pi i \xi)^2f(\xi)$...